# Issue with getting value from $.ajax inside a $.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog

Hey guys I have the following code:

```
function runATF(){
        var urlatf = '/pcg/ATF/updateATF_window.php';
        var tagatf = $("#insider_dialog");

        var promise1 = showUrlInDialogATF(urlatf);
        var promise2 = sendUpdateATFwindow();

        $.when(promise1, promise2).done(function(data1, data2) {

            tagatf.html(data1[0]).dialog({
              width: '100%',
              modal: true
            }).dialog('open');
           //$('.updaterATF_outerbody').text(data2[0].atfName),
           //$('.updaterATF_outerbody').text(data2[0].atfAmount)
           //console.log(data2[1]);
          alert(data2[0].text(atfName));
              alert(data2[0].text(atfAmount));
        });
    }
```

The part I need you to look at it the `alert(data2[0].text(atfName));` and the `alert(data2[0].text(atfAmount));`  My problem is I can't seem to get the values?

Let me show you the 2 functions that are ran:

First this one just sends a url and returns....

```
function showUrlInDialogATF(urlatf)
    {
      return $.ajax({
        url: urlatf
      });
    }
```

The second one returns the two data values that are created in a `document.ready` (I have tested them and they do hold values, it's only when I try and get it into the `$.when` statement).....

```
function sendUpdateATFwindow()
    {
      return $.ajax({
        data: {
            'atfName': atf_name.val(),
            'atfAmount': atf_amount.val()
        }
      });
    }
```

Let me know if you need anything else, thank you

David

Oh here is the first statement that begins everything:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        $(".atf-submit").click(function () {
                atf_name = $(this).parent().parent().find(".user_table");
                atf_amount = $(this).parent().parent().find(".user_atf");
         runATF();
        });
    });
```

Note:  I am using the Jquery UI dialog opener,  I already have one open so I am making another one open.  I don't know if this will effect anything?  I would assume not because the functions and values are different names.

UPDATE:

Okay I want to show the first code that opens the first dialog window up:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        $("#ATF").click(function () {

          runATF();
        });
    });

    function runATF(){
        var urlATF = '/pcg/ATF/atf_layout.php';
        showUrlInDialogATF(urlATF);
    }
    function showUrlInDialogATF(urlATF)
    {
      var tag = $("#dialog-container");
      $.ajax({
        url: urlATF,
        success: function(data) {
          tag.html(data).dialog
          ({
              width: '100%',
                modal: true
          }).dialog('open');
        }
      });
    }
```

Than the other code runs - I will re post here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {     
        $(".atf-submit").click(function () {
                atf_name = $(this).parent().parent().find(".user_table");
                atf_amount = $(this).parent().parent().find(".user_atf");
         runATFinsider();
        });
    });
function runATFinsider(){
        var urlatfinsider = '/pcg/ATF/updateATF_window.php';
        var tagatfinsider = $("#insider_dialog");

        var promise1 = showUrlInDialogATFinsider(urlatfinsider);
        var promise2 = sendUpdateATFwindow();

        $.when(promise1, promise2).done(function(data1, data2) {

            tagatfinsider.html(data1[0]).dialog({
              width: '100%',
              modal: true
            }).dialog('open');
           //$('.updaterATF_outerbody').text(data2[0].atfName),
           //$('.updaterATF_outerbody').text(data2[0].atfAmount)
           console.log(data2[1]);
          alert(data2[0].text(atfName));
        });
    }
    function showUrlInDialogATFinsider(urlatfinsider)
    {
      return $.ajax({
        url: urlatfinsider
      });
    }
    function sendUpdateATFwindow()
    {
      return $.ajax({
        data: {
            'atfName': atf_name.val(),
            'atfAmount': atf_amount.val()
        }
      });
    }
```

Also I try to do a `console.log(data2)` and it just gives me, [0] = `abunch of html?` , [1] = `success`, [2] = `object`

UPDATE:

Here is an example of what it I should be getting in the data2[0]...

```
alert(atf_name.val()); = bob
alert(atf_amount.val()); = 0
```

Comment: What do you expect `alert(data2[0].text(atfName))` to display? `.text()` should be applied to a jQuery object, not the returned data from an AJAX call.

Comment: can you inspect what your `data1` and `data2` parameters look like when you enter the `done` callback?

Comment: If `data2[0]` contains a bunch of HTML, that's what the AJAX server is returning.

Comment: But why I am returning the results of atf_name and atf_amount?

Comment: That last comment basically reads *"Why am i doing this?"* only you know that... can you elaborate?

Comment: Lol sorry,  Why is it sending the HTML instead of the values I returned in the $.ajax?  It shouldn't do that.

Comment: @KevinB I am not sure why it is return HTML when I returned the values of the 2 variables I sent in?